# How to add data to plots while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib

I have some clinical data that contains values for multiple visits for multiple subjects.  I created a script to loop and create a plot for each subject containing values for each visit.  Now, I need to add data to each subject plot:

1. For each subject, add a new marker (star) to identify the baseline value (bcva_OS and bcva_OD) only.  I can only get it to display the the markers for all values.  How do I subset for baseline only?  See comment in the code. I get a syntax error if I use:

   `plt.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'] if sub_df[sub_df.visit_label == 'Visit 2 - Baseline'],`
2. For each subject, how can I add an entirely new data type so that both data types will be overlayed on a plot for each subject?  I think I could do that with just one subject's worth of data, but again the loop...

**Sample code:**

```
for subject, sub_df in new_od_df.groupby(by='subject'):

    # Plot fellow eye
    plt.plot(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OS'], marker='^', 
        label='OS (fellow) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['pale red'])

    # Plot treated eye
    plt.plot(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OD'], marker='o',
        label='OD (treated) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['denim blue']) 

    # Trying to plot only the baseline values
    #plt.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'] if sub_df[sub_df.visit_label == 'Visit 2 - Baseline'], 

    # Plot fellow eye
    plt.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OS'], 
        marker='*', markersize=10,
        label='BL (fellow) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['light pink'])

    # Plot treated eye
    plt.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OD'], 
        marker='*', markersize=10,
        label='BL (treated) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['baby blue'])

    # Legend the old way
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)

    # Display each chart separately
    plt.show()
```

**Sample data:**

```
       subject treated_eye              visit_label  visit_date  bcva_OD  bcva_OS         refract_OD         refract_OS
index                                                                                                                  
108       1101          OD      Visit 1 - Screening  2016-01-07     27.0     41.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 27    + 5 + 1.75 X 45
115       1101          OD       Visit 2 - Baseline  2016-01-25     35.0     41.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 27  + 5.5 + 1.75 X 40
120       1101          OD  Baseline - VA Session 2  2016-01-25     35.0     41.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 27  + 5.5 + 1.75 X 40
125       1101          OD          Visit 4 - Day 1  2016-02-02     32.0     42.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 27    + 5 + 1.75 X 30
123       1101          OD          Visit 5 - Day 7  2016-02-08     40.0     43.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 28    + 5 + 1.75 X 30
111       1101          OD         Visit 6 - Day 14  2016-02-16     33.0     44.0    + 5 + 0.75 X 27    + 5 + 1.75 X 40
124       1101          OD              Unscheduled  2016-02-24     37.0     44.0  + 4.5 + 1.25 X 30    + 5 + 1.75 X 40
118       1101          OD        Visit 7 - Month 1  2016-02-29     37.0     40.0  + 4.5 + 1.25 X 30    + 5 + 1.75 X 43
```

**Sample plot:**

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Rather than posting your sample data as images, can you post them as code so they can be easily copied?  That will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I updated the data, but I'm not sure if my update is helpful.

Comment: That's definitely better - but best would be if you can put it in the form: `df = pd.DataFrame( ... )` - then you can be sure that people are working with your sample data exactly as intended.

Comment: I think you should be able to plot the masked values like `plt.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'][ mask ])` where `mask=(sub_df[sub_df.visit_label == 'Visit 2 - Baseline'])`

Comment: @Asmus, this results in 'TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column

Comment: @gadkins what is `print(type(sub_df))` and `print(type(new_od_df))`?

Comment: @Asmus both are <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.  This is what you are asking, correct?

Comment: @gadkins I've added a partial answer below (regarding your point 1) but I don't quite understand your point 2; could you rephrase that?

Comment: @Asmus, thanks very much.  I like what you did, but was going for something a bit different: 1) add the light pink/blue markers to identify the 'Visit 2 - Baseline' values only; they are showing for all time points currently.  Alternatively, the line could be vertical at the baseline values. 2) overlay a completely different data frame on this graph, for example population of China over time with y-axis on right.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this is a partial answer to point 1:*

I'm not sure I completely understood your requests, especially regarding point 2: creating a new data type. Please edit your question to make point 2 clearer. Right now I'm *guessing* you want to plot both OD and OS values after baseline-subtraction, is this correct?

Regarding point 1, the solution below correctly gets the baseline values and plots them as a dashed line. Note that I've also added a plot title and changed calls to `plt.` to `ax.`, after properly creating a figure using `fig,ax=plt.subplots()`. This may come in handy later, and is already required for `fig.autofmt_xdate()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns

data="""index,subject,treated_eye,visit_label,visit_date,bcva_OD,bcva_OS,refract_OD,refract_OS
108, 1101,    OD,  Visit 1 - Screening, 2016-01-07,  27.0,   41.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 27, + 5 + 1.75 X 45
115, 1101,    OD,  Visit 2 - Baseline,  2016-01-25,  35.0,   41.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 27, + 5.5 + 1.75 X 40
120, 1101,    OD,  Baseline - VA Session 2 ,2016-01-25, 35.0,   41.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 27, + 5.5 + 1.75 X 40
125, 1101,    OD,  Visit 4 - Day 1 ,2016-02-02, 32.0,   42.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 27, + 5 + 1.75 X 30
123, 1101,    OD,  Visit 5 - Day 7 ,2016-02-08, 40.0,   43.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 28, + 5 + 1.75 X 30
111, 1101,    OD,  Visit 6 - Day 14    ,2016-02-16,33.0,   44.0,    + 5 + 0.75 X 27, + 5 + 1.75 X 40
124, 1101,    OD,  Unscheduled ,2016-02-24, 37.0,   44.0,    + 4.5 + 1.25 X 30,   + 5 + 1.75 X 40
118, 1101,    OD,  Visit 7 - Month 1 ,  2016-02-29 , 37.0,   40.0,    + 4.5 + 1.25 X 30,   + 5 + 1.75 X 43
"""

## DataFrame cleanup
df=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),sep=",",index_col=0)
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

df['visit_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date'])

for subject, sub_df in df.groupby(by='subject'):
    mask=(sub_df.visit_label == 'Visit 2 - Baseline')
    bcva_OS_baseline=sub_df['bcva_OS'][mask].values
    bcva_OD_baseline=sub_df['bcva_OD'][mask].values

    fig,ax=plt.subplots()    

    # Plot fellow eye
    ax.plot(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OS'], marker='^', 
        label='OS (fellow) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['pale red'])

    # Plot treated eye
    ax.plot(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OD'], marker='o',
        label='OD (treated) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['denim blue']) 

    # Plot fellow eye
    ax.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OS'], 
        marker='*', markersize=10,
        label='BL (fellow) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['light pink'])

    # Plot treated eye
    ax.plot_date(sub_df['visit_date'], sub_df['bcva_OD'], 
        marker='*', markersize=10,
        label='BL (treated) ', color=sns.xkcd_rgb['baby blue'])

    # Plot baseline
    ax.axhline(bcva_OS_baseline,color=sns.xkcd_rgb['pale red'],linestyle="dashed")
    ax.axhline(bcva_OD_baseline,color=sns.xkcd_rgb['denim blue'],linestyle="dashed")

    # Legend the old way
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)

    # Display each chart separately
    ax.set_title('subject {0}'.format(subject))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

**Result:**
[image: Plot result]